# Extension attributes and api functional testing

Tags: phpunit, api-functional-tests

When running api functional tests on a module which uses non-scalar array extension attribute type, I've got the error

`ReflectionException: Class "ModuleName\Customer\Api\CustomAddressInterface[]" does not exist`

the attribute is declared as:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_addresses" type="ModuleName\Customer\Api\CustomAddressInterface[]" />
</extension_attributes>
```

The module works perfectly outside the testing framework

I run the tests as:

`vendor/bin/phpunit -c $(pwd)/dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml --testsuite testsuite`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "ReflectionException: Class 'ModuleName\Customer\Api\CustomAddressInterface[]' does not exist," is likely due to the way you've defined the extension attribute type in the extension_attributes.xml file. In this case, the issue appears to be with the type attribute.

Instead of specifying the type as an array like this:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_addresses" type="ModuleName\Customer\Api\CustomAddressInterface[]" />
</extension_attributes>
```

You should define the type as an interface and use an array in your implementation to store multiple instances of the custom address. Update your extension_attributes.xml to:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_addresses" type="ModuleName\Customer\Api\CustomAddressInterface" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Then, in your implementation of the Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface, use an array to store the custom_addresses attribute. For example, in your Company model class (which should implement Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface), you can implement the getter and setter for the custom_addresses attribute like this:

```
public function getCustomAddresses(): array
{
    return $this->_get(self::CUSTOM_ADDRESSES) ?: [];
}

public function setCustomAddresses(array $customAddresses): \Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface
{
    return $this->setData(self::CUSTOM_ADDRESSES, $customAddresses);
}
```

With these changes, your functional tests should run without the ReflectionException error. Make sure to update your code to work with the new implementation of the custom_addresses attribute.

After updating your extension_attributes.xml and your implementation of the Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface, you should follow these steps to ensure everything works as expected:

Clear generated code and cache:

Run the following commands to clear generated code and cache to make sure Magento picks up your changes:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Run the Magento setup upgrade:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This command ensures that your module's changes are applied to the database schema and data.

Compile your code:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This step generates any necessary dependency injection configurations and optimizes the application's performance.

Verify your changes:

Test your module again to ensure that it still functions correctly with the updated implementation. Check that the custom_addresses attribute works as expected when interacting with the Magento\Company\Api\Data\CompanyInterface.

Rerun your functional tests:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c $(pwd)/dev/tests/api-functional/phpunit_rest.xml --testsuite testsuite
```

With the updated implementation, your functional tests should now run without encountering the ReflectionException error.

If you still face any issues, review your code changes and ensure that all necessary updates have been made to work with the new implementation of the custom_addresses attribute. Additionally, verify that your functional tests are correctly set up and cover the expected functionality of your module.

Comment: I assumed the declaration correct given the doc references to this example https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-external-links/etc/extension_attributes.xml where a non-scalar is declared as array []